# Azure keyvault extention is not updating the ssl bindings in IIS but client is able to recieve updated certificate

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, virtual-machine, azure-keyvault, azure-vm-scale-set

I have an iis hosted website on Azure windows 19 server.
To update the certificate for ssl binding I have installed keyvault extention on the vm.
Hoping if I push new version of certificate in keyvault then vms will automatically pull the certificate and apply it on IIS ssl binding.
But when I update the certificate in keyvault , extention is able to pull the certificate and put in windows My localstore. But it is not updating the corresponding ssl binding in iis with new certificate.
Moreover if I browse https://localhost then I see the client is getting latest certificate(new version).

Not able to get where it is creating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the PowerShell script to update the IIS SSL binding:

```
    $PublicSettings = '{
    "fileUris":["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/compute-automation-configurations/master/secure-iis.ps1"],
    "commandToExecute":"powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File secure-iis.ps1"
}'

Set-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
    -ExtensionName "IIS" `
    -VMName "myVM" `
    -Location $location `
    -Publisher "Microsoft.Compute" `
    -ExtensionType "CustomScriptExtension" `
    -TypeHandlerVersion 1.8 `
    -SettingString $publicSettings
```

For more detail please refer to below article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-secure-web-server#configure-iis-to-use-the-certificate

Comment: I wanted to automate certificate update from keyvault. This method will just add the certificate one time. How do I push any new version of the certificate with out redeploying my vm?

Comment: @raunak you do not need to redeploy the Azure VM gain just need to update the Azure VM with a new key vault certificate and run the extension 'Set-AzVMExtension'  for a binding certificate in IIS again.